# a hard function question

Tags: functions

Compute $f^{(n)}(0)$, where $f : \Bbb{R} → \Bbb{R}$ is the function defined by $f(x) = x^ne^x$, $∀x ∈ \Bbb{R}$, where $n ∈ \Bbb{N}$ is fixed.

Comment: Do you know Leibniz Formula

Comment: unfortunately, i dont know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We know the Taylor expansion for the exponential function $\exp(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!}$. This implies

$$f(x)=x^n\exp(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m+n}}{m!}.$$

Now, compare this with the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$

$$f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{f^{(m)}(0)}{m!}x^m$$

to obtain $f^{(n)}(0)$. The term associated with this is 
$$\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n,$$

which implies that $m=0$ must hold in the first expansion 
$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m+n}}{m!}.$$

Can you complete it from here? The term for $m=0$ is equal to $$1\cdot x^n.$$ Hence, we can conclude $1=\dfrac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\implies n!=f^{(n)}(0)$.

Comment: I researched taylor expansion, it is not maclaurin sequence, is it?

Comment: Need more help if you can

Comment: @mathematiciankk: I added the solution.